# Can I have multiple tables with same parent in Google Spanner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

I read that we can have maximum table interleaving depth of 6 in Google Spanner and an interleaved table can have only one direct parent table, But can we have multiple tables with same parent?

For Example:

```
TableA (root)
TableB (INTERLEAVE IN PARENT TableA)
TableC (INTERLEAVE IN PARENT TableA)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can. The following DDL is for example accepted:

```
CREATE TABLE `PARENT` (
  ID INT64 NOT NULL,
  DESCRIPTION STRING(100) NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(ID);

CREATE TABLE CHILD1 (
  ID INT64 NOT NULL,
  CHILD1_ID INT64 NOT NULL,
  CHILD1_DESCRIPTION STRING(100) NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(ID, CHILD1_ID),
  INTERLEAVE IN PARENT `PARENT` ON DELETE NO ACTION;

CREATE TABLE CHILD2 (
  ID INT64 NOT NULL,
  CHILD2_ID INT64 NOT NULL,
  CHILD2_DESCRIPTION STRING(100) NOT NULL,
) PRIMARY KEY(ID, CHILD2_ID),
  INTERLEAVE IN PARENT `PARENT` ON DELETE NO ACTION
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Our infrastructure team has not set Spanner yet ,so I couldn't try it. Just wanted to know if it's possible.